# How to switch/downgrade amplify core version under flutter plugins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, dart, aws-amplify

I'm kinda new to android studio and am still getting used to the user interface. I have a flutter project where I am trying to use the amplify library(**import 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart';**) to set up a login for the app but the plugin I am using(**amplify_core-0.0.2-dev.2)** seems to be having issues importing all the amplify functions(as in it won't recognize them even though they exist) and an example app I was looking at which was recognizing the functions from the amplify class was using **amplify_core-0.0.1-dev.4**. I figured the best solution would be to downgrade the the amplify core I was using on that project but I'm not sure exactly how to switch it(adding '**amplify_core: '^0.0.1-dev.4'**' in the pubspec.yaml but nothing changed), how would I go about doing that? Thanks!

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMkP2.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncQ85.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue is you didn't `get` the packages after changing the `pubspec.yaml` file. After saving the file, click on the `pub get` button on the top right. Or open the terminal in that folder and run `flutter pub get`.